# Reference Item State Not Updated in React Redux on Save

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux, react-redux

My blog model has a reference to my users model in mongoose (and vice versa). In my Blog application, when I go to create a Blog post for a User, the blogs state is updated, but when i examine the user's state in the redux store, the user's associated blogs are not updated.  If i refresh my page which displays the user, it does ultimately refresh to show the updated blog post, but not sure why the state is not updating immediately.

Thus, here is starting code where I create a new blog post:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createBlog } from "../reducers/blogReducer";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { setNotification } from "../reducers/notificationReducer";
import { useField } from "../hooks";
import { Form } from "semantic-ui-react";

const NewBlog = props => {
  const newTitle = useField("text");
  const newAuthor = useField("text");
  const newURL = useField("text");

  const addBlog = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const blogObject = {
      url: newURL.value,
      title: newTitle.value,
      author: newAuthor.value
    };
    props.createBlog(blogObject);
    props.history.push("/blogs");
    setNotification(`New Blog Created!`, 4);
    newTitle.reset();
    newAuthor.reset();
    newURL.reset();
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={addBlog}>
      <Form.Field>
        <Form.Input {...newTitle} reset={null} label="Title" id="title" />
      </Form.Field>
      <Form.Field>
        <Form.Input {...newAuthor} reset={null} label="Author" id="author" />
      </Form.Field>
      <Form.Field>
        <Form.Input {...newURL} reset={null} label="URL" id="url" />
      </Form.Field>
      <Form.Button type="submit">add blog</Form.Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  createBlog,
  setNotification
};

const AddBlog = withRouter(NewBlog);

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddBlog);
```

here is my createBlog action creator (and reducer)

```
export const createBlog = content => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const newBlog = await blogService.create(content);
    dispatch({
      type: "NEW_BLOG",
      data: newBlog
    });
  };
};

  case "NEW_BLOG":
      return [...state, action.data];
```

and axios create call

```
const create = async newObject => {
  const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: token }
  };
  const response = await axios

.post(baseUrl, newObject, config);
      return response.data;
    };
```

and then my backend where the post is called:

```
blogsRouter.post("/", async (request, response, next) => {
  const data = request.body;

  const token = getTokenFrom(request);

  try {
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
    if (!token || !decodedToken.id) {
      return response.status(401).json({ error: "token missing or invalid" });
    }

    const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id);

    const blog = new Blog({
      title: data.title,
      author: data.author,
      likes: isNaN(data.likes) ? 0 : data.likes,
      url: data.url,
      user: user._id
    });

    const savedBlog = await blog.save();
    user.blogs = user.blogs.concat(savedBlog._id);
    await user.save();
    response.status(201).json(savedBlog.toJSON());
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

my full Router container in App.js

```
<Container>
      <Router>
        <Notification />
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login">
              <Login />
            </Route>
            {props.loggedUser && (
              <React.Fragment>
                <Route exact path="/">
                  <Blogs />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/blogs">
                  <Blogs />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/newblog">
                  <AddBlog />
                </Route>
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/blogs/:id"
                  render={({ match }) => (
                    <Blog
                      blog={blogById(match.params.id)}
                      user={props.loggedUser}
                      history={props.history}
                    />
                  )}
                />
                <Route exact path="/users">
                  <Users />
                </Route>
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/users/:id"
                  render={({ match }) => (
                    <User user={userById(match.params.id)} />
                  )}
                />
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
            <Route exact path="/newuser">
              <CreateUser />
            </Route>
            <Redirect to="/login">
              <Login />
            </Redirect>
            )}
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
      <div>
        <br />
        <em>Blog app, John 2019</em>
      </div>
    </Container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting to your blogs page in the same event loop as the function call that initiates saving the blog to your database. You need to wait for the blog post to be saved first then you can redirect:

```
  const addBlog = async event => { // <-- make it async
    event.preventDefault();

    const blogObject = {
      url: newURL.value,
      title: newTitle.value,
      author: newAuthor.value
    };
    await props.createBlog(blogObject); // <-- wait for it to finish
    props.history.push("/blogs");
    setNotification(`New Blog Created!`, 4);
    newTitle.reset();
    newAuthor.reset();
    newURL.reset();
  };
```

Comment: ah, you are brilliant, i learned a lot from your concise explanation.  i thought this would do the trick, but it brought up an error, and still not updating the state. I've never seen this one before `index.js:1375 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in NewBlog (created by Context.Consumer)
    in withRouter(NewBlog) (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at App.js:76)`

Comment: note this is line 76 in my App.js file `<Route exact path="/newblog"><AddBlog /</Route>` also posted my full Router container above

Comment: If you remove all your `.reset()` calls after `setNotification` does the warning go away? There's no reason to reset anything on a page you are navigating away from

Comment: yep, that does remove the error!  but the user blogs still aren't updating...agggh...unless i refresh the page

Comment: Where in your code do you update your user state? Can you post that code? Maybe you're just straight up not actually saving it to your user state when save the blog post. Could you add your user reducer?

Comment: thought this might be easier to post git https://github.com/pythoncreate/full-stack-open/tree/master/part7/blog-test

Comment: i think you are right, the createBlog action creator is adding the new blog to the blogs state, but there is nothing on that call to update the user state.  is there a way to do that within the createBlog creator or do i need to do a separate call when i create a new blog post?

Comment: All you should need to do is listen for `NEW_BLOG` action in your UserReducer and update your user with the blog / blog id (or whatever the association is)

Comment: quick question on your last comment.  so if i add 'NEW_BLOG' listener in userReducer, i guess i would need to call another action creator after i call the action creator which creates the blog...one to update user, is that correct?